# Minimum of a variable and a constant in PULP python integer programming

Tags: min, pulp

I am stuck with a problem in Integer Programming constraint using PULP in python. I have 2 variables x1, x2 and a constant y. How do i write a constraint on x1 = min(x2 ,y1).

I have written below two condition:
x1 < y1;

x1 < x2

But it is giving me x1 = 0 for my problem.
It should take one of the values from x2 and y1

Thanks in advance. Will really appreciate your help.

**Code used:**

```
*import pandas as pd
from pulp import *

data = pd.read_csv("Test.csv")
limit = LpVariable("limit",0, 1000, cat='Integer')
sales = LpVariable.dicts("Sales", (i for i in data.index), lowBound=0,  cat="Integer")

####### Defining the Problem
prob = pulp.LpProblem("Profit", pulp.LpMaximize)
prob += pulp.lpSum((1-data.loc[i,'Prize']) * sales[i] for i in data.index)

####### Constraints
for idx in data.index:
    max_sales = data.loc[idx, 'Sales'] + data.loc[idx, 'Rejec']
    prob += sales[idx] <= max_sales
    prob += sales[idx] <= limit

###### Getting the output    
prob.solve()
for v in prob.variables():
    print v.name,v.varValue

print value(prob.objective)
```

**Data Used (try.csv)** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLYtP.png)

Comment: You should show your code.

Comment: Edited the Question with the code and the data... Hope it helps.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/36245856/1531971 help?

Comment: No.. this the above is not helpful.. as i am maximizing my profit and the optimized sales takes value of 0 where prize >0 but it should take one value - either limit or sales.. that is is the reason I want to put a condition that optimized sales should be min of sales and limit and not less than equal to sales and limit

Comment: Comments like that should be in the body of the question.